# How to call the system default player to play the video?

Tags: android, video

I am developing an application. I want to realize a function like that I want to call the system default player.

After downloading the custom Audio or video file. Could it play using the system audio and video player in the program?

I want to create intent, and give the file path. Then call the system’s player.

any idears？

Comment: Do you want explicitly only the system player, or do you want any player capable of playing the file? Or you want to play it in your Activity (and therefore not using an Intent?)

Comment: http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/29/android-videomusic-player-sample-from-local-disk-as-well-as-remote-urls/

Answer (score 4):

Try This

```
videourl="/sdcard/zzzz.3gp";

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(videourl)); 

startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

For **kotlin**:

```
val path: String = contentUri.getPath()
val file = File(path)
val intent = Intent(
Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.fromFile(file))
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(path), "video/*")
startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(videourl));
startActivity(intent);
```

The above code should works for you to play video files

Answer (score 0):

```
String video = "http://www.nandudu.com/hls/course/video/2/test.m3u8";  

Intent openVideo = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  

openVideo.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(video), "video/*");  

startActivity(openVideo);
```